# xtabs function loop for different IDs

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am just starting to write functions and loops and ran across a problem:
I am trying to use the xtabs function to find frequencies for several subject IDs seperately and cannot figure out how to do this.

So I have a dataframe and would usually do this across all IDs

```
xtabs(~choice+ diff+indicator, data = df)
```

However I want to do it seperately for each ID and then do more analyses (e.g. mean choice probabilities).

I tried to do it by splitting the df

```
split_df<-split(df, df$ID)
for (b in seq_along(split_df)) {
 print(xtabs(choice + diff+indicator, data = split_df[[b]]))
}
```

Ideally, I would like to have a list of dataframes with the results (one per ID) and then do more analyses with it. I cannot figure this out though.
Alternatively, it may be possible with some built in function but I am not aware of one.

Thanks
Laura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use case for either `by` or `lapply` rather than a `for`-loop. Basically, the result is the same, but without the overhead of writing a loop, iterating over it, and storing the results appropriate. Here's a simple example like yours that uses the built-in `mtcars` dataset:

```
b <- by(mtcars, mtcars$gear, FUN = function(d) xtabs(~cyl + vs + am, data = d))
l <- lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$gear), FUN = function(d) xtabs(~cyl + vs + am, data = d))
```

We can use `str` to take a look at what we created:

```
> str(b, 1)
List of 3
 $ 3: xtabs [1:3, 1:2, 1] 0 0 12 1 2 0
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xtabs" "table"
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = ~cyl + vs + am, data = d)
 $ 4: xtabs [1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 0 0 2 2 0 2 6 0
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xtabs" "table"
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = ~cyl + vs + am, data = d)
 $ 5: xtabs [1:3, 1:2, 1] 1 1 2 1 0 0
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xtabs" "table"
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = ~cyl + vs + am, data = d)
 - attr(*, "dim")= int 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
 - attr(*, "call")= language by.data.frame(data = mtcars, INDICES = mtcars$gear, FUN = function(d) xtabs(~cyl + vs + am, data = d))
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "by"

> str(l, 1)
List of 3
 $ 3: xtabs [1:3, 1:2, 1] 0 0 12 1 2 0
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xtabs" "table"
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = ~cyl + vs + am, data = d)
 $ 4: xtabs [1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 0 0 2 2 0 2 6 0
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xtabs" "table"
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = ~cyl + vs + am, data = d)
 $ 5: xtabs [1:3, 1:2, 1] 1 1 2 1 0 0
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xtabs" "table"
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = ~cyl + vs + am, data = d)
```

In this case, I think the result from `lapply` is probably closer to what you're going for, but (as you can hopefully see) the structures are very similar - both are lists of `xtabs` objects.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I want, and a good example which matches my own. Do you know how to access the different tables after doing this in order to combine everything in a dataframe or something like this to do further analysis? for example if I use b[[2]] there are two subtables, once with am=0 and once with am=1.

Comment: Yes, `xtabs` spits out an "array", which you can index using `[`. Take a look at `dim(b[[2]])` to see the dimensions of each array, for example. So you should be able to do `b[[2]][1,1,1]` to extract a given value from each array.